# How can you create a Location Object for your TestDataFactory?

Tags: apex

This is what I have done:

```
public static List<Schema.Location> createLocations(Integer numLoc) {
        List<Schema.Location> lList = new List<Schema.Location>();

        for (Integer i = 0; i < numLoc; i++) {
            Schema.Location l = new Schema.Location();

            lList.add(l);
        }

        insert lList;
        return lList;
    }
```

This is the error I get:

> Expected type [`SObject`, `List<SObject>`]; found `List<Location>` less... (Ctrl+F1)
>   Inspection info:This inspection reports illegal assignments and comparisons as a result of incompatible types.

Comment: Is there a stack trace? Perhaps you have built out a trigger that is throwing this error?